# How to use react-router to jump to specific location in the page

Tags: reactjs, parallax, react-router

I am trying to build a parallax website with react and react-router

In most react-router examples I found, target dom node is replaced with Handler corresponding to the route.

```
var routes = (
    <Route handler={App} path="/">
        <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />
        <Route name="about" handler={About} />
        <Route name="users" handler={Users} />
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

How can I render all the route handlers into single page and jump to specific location in a page with react-router ?

Comment: Sounds like you would need path variables inside of the routes that would determine where to scroll too. https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/overview.md#dynamic-segments

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is the `<Link to="#LOCATION" />`. It says in the documentation about the **to** attribute of the **Link** tag: ***The name of the route to link to, or a full URL.***. Try that and see if that works.