# Jumping to specific location in a page in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, page-jump

I need to go to a specific line on page, when clicking on a button. How can it be done using react-router.I have :

```
<Grid xs={3}>    
  <Button>heading</Button>
  <Button>Heading2</Button>
</Grid>
<Grid xs={3}>    
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <h2>Heading2</h2>
  <p>Paragraph2</p>
</Grid>
```

When clicking on heading button, it should jump to the relevant place in 2nd grid. How it can be done. I referred, [How to use react-router to jump to specific location in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590040/how-to-use-react-router-to-jump-to-specific-location-in-the-page) as well.

Comment: I have updated my answer.check it out

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Link` component in MUI `Button` and define an id attribute for your second grid,say `gridWrapper`.

```
<Grid xs={3}>    
  <Button component={Link} to="#gridWrapper">heading</Button>
  <Button>Heading2</Button>
</Grid>
<Grid xs={3} id="gridWrapper">    
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <h2>Heading2</h2>
  <p>Paragraph2</p>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do we need to define something in react router?

Comment: Clicking on the button, it changes the url, but not redirecting